# wordpress website displaing image and image path

Tags: wordpress, image

Recently I noticed in my Wordpress website that in all the pages, when I have an image to display, it displays the image and right after it displays the path to the image, including the image properties. The entire

Can someone helpe, please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STVn0.jpg)

Comment: I have already disabled all plugins but it didn't solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your HTML Structure breaks with your PHP Code. you need to check your code where you getting this Image. This is how its showing from Inspect Element:

```
<img src="http://antiparosbeauty.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/weding.jpg" alt="weding" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-140" srcset="http://antiparosbeauty.gr/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/weding.jpg 345w, <a href=" http:="" antiparosbeauty.gr="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2014="" 03="" weding-300x141.jpg"="" target="_blank" height="163" width="345">
```